# How can I get a specific attribute value?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack, selectsinglenode

There is an input element as below:

```
<input type="hidden" value="908" name="a">
```

I want to return `908` value using `DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode`. How can I do this?
The code below does not work?

```
string a = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='a']").GetAttributeValue("value", true).ToString();
```

Comment: Try `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='a']/@value/text()")`

Comment: nope -> exception = Object reference not set to an instance of an object. :) (jesus = your rank is 192515 - do you want to F.. yourself? do you live in stack?) what is the highest rank in stackoverflow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the wrong overload for `GetAttributeValue()`. Try using a string as the second parameter instead of a boolean:

```
string a = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='a']").GetAttributeValue("value", "default");
```